# pixijs adding an outer glow with a gradient behind the letters

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I'm adding in a score at the end of this pixijs game. 
I have the standard parameters here - but the design calls for an outerglow around the letters is there a way to do this?
http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/docs/classes/Text.html

```
this.txtRankingOverall = new PIXI.Text("" + GameControl.score, {
    font: "120px FSJoeyLtIt",
    fill: "#ffffff",
    align: "center"
});
```

[image]

I'm also having issues trying to match the font - it needs to be italic light

```
 this.txtRankingToday = new PIXI.Text("46", {
            font: "italic 120px FSJoeyLtIt",
            fill: "#ffffff",
            align: "center",
            style: "light"
        });
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/N476t/10/ here is a jsfiddle using arial - I have problems trying to invoke light italic

Comment: I am having some luck with this code - but at times the style doesnt take hold - this.txtRankingOverall = new PIXI.Text("324", {
            font: "lighter italic 120px FSJoeyLtIt",
            fill: "red",
            align: "center"
        });

Comment: You are probably better off using BitmapText for any custom artistic fonts:
http://pixijs.github.io/docs/PIXI.extras.BitmapText.html